# Как при запуске PHP storm автоматически запустить команду "php artisan serve"

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста, как в PHPstorm при открытии автоматически запустить "php artisan serve" и "npm run dev"? Я прибывал заходить в "Startup Tasks" -> "нажимал "+" -> выбирал "Add New Configuration", а дальше что?

Answer (score 0):

"Add New Configuration" -> "Shell Script" -> "Script text". И в Script Text вписывайте команду. Потом сможете еще добавить

Answer (score 0):

1. Зайти в "**Edit Configurations...**".
2. Добавить "npm": "**Add New Configuration**" -> "**npm**". Выбрать "**Command**": **run**, "**Scripts**": **dev**
3. Добавить "PHP Script": "**Add New Configuration**" -> "**PHP Script**".
   В разделе "**Configuration**", в поле "**File**", указать путь к файлу **С:\{Путь до вашего проекта}\artisan** а  в поле "**Arguments**" ввести: **serve**
4. Добавить "Compound", для того чтобы запустить несколько конфигураций одновременно:
   "**Add New Configuration**" -> "**Compound**". Добавить туда созданные ранее конфигурации.
5. Запустить конфигурацию "**Compound**".